# See non-featured questions for a tag

Tags: support, tags, questions, search

When I search for questions with a given tag by entering, for instance:

> [gurps]

into the search bar, or by clicking a tag like [gurps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps), I invariably end up on a page telling me there are no featured questions with this tag.

But I'm not interested in **featured** questions. I just wanted to see all the questions with that tag.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get to **all** of the questions with a given tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're on the wrong tab? Try clicking the "Newest" or "Active" tab... When I click on a tag link, I get the list of questions.

Edit: Hmmm, odd. I don't actually see ALL the questions tagged GURPS when I choose "newest."

Edit 2: Nevermind the above. They're both still there... Just the "author" block changes depending on view.

Comment: Clicking "newest" solved the problem. I guess I expected to get that by default when searching / clicking on a tag.

Comment: @gomad It's possible that you clicked on the "featured" tab at some point in the past (possibly with a different list of questions), and SE "helpfully" remembered that for you. I always get whatever the last tab I was looking at previously.

Comment: I don't think so, it's always been a nagging problem for me on RPG.SE. But, it's helpfully remembering it **now**, so it won't be a problem anymore!